# Reload other page when clicking button "refresh"

Tags: javascript, html

On the current page, add button "Refresh".

Process: when the user clicks this button "Refresh", then this page link "https://abc.io/123" refreshes and do not open this link (not new page), still stay on the current page.

My code doesn't work:

```
<a href="https://abc.io/123" onClick="window.location.reload();return false;">
<i class="fas fa-sync-alt fa-1.5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#0000FF;"></i><span style="color:blue;"> Refresh</span>
</a>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you intend to open new page or not?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor not open new page, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `onClick` should be `onclick`. This will reload the page, except if the DOMException gets thrown, which blocks the reload. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).
By default, the page gets reloaded from the browser cache. To force reload it from the server, pass `true` to `window.location.reload()`.

```html
<a href="https://abc.io/123" onclick="window.location.reload(); return false;">
<i class="fas fa-sync-alt fa-1.5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#0000FF;"></i><span style="color:blue;"> Refresh</span>
</a>
```

If you intend to open the link as well, `return true` from the onclick function.